# Adding Dynamically created button into canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

How to append a dynamically created button into a canvas element using JavaScript?

Help me with an example.

Comment: First off, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be sure to check out these docs - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - to be better informed about how to properly ask questions on here. Second, what have you tried so far to solve this problem?

Comment: Also, canvas elements only display their HTML "content" if the browser is not canvas-compatible, and I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: The canvas element cannot contain a button element. A workaround is to wrap the canvas in a div. Then create your button and add it to the wrapper div. Make the wrapper `position:relative` and make both the canvas and the button `position:absolute` so they are both positioned in the wrapper. Then use `top` & `left` to position the button as desired over the canvas. You can do this natively [using javascript](https://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/vLgeay71/) but it's easier using jQuery

Comment: But you can draw a pixel shape that will act as a button if you do compare click event coordinates with the ones of your shape.